# Custom post type post taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I created simple custom post type with few taxonomies. I

```
<?php $query_params = getQueryParams(); $query_params['post_type'] = 'client'; 
    if(isset($query_params['search'])){
        $query_params['post_title_like'] = $query_params['search'];
        unset($query_params['search']);
    }
    $loop = new WP_Query($query_params);
    if($loop->have_posts()) : while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post(); 

    // SOME HTML

    endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Then I tried to list display taxonomies for each post, by this:

```
$categories = get_categories("taxonomy=city");

foreach ($categories as $category) :

echo '&lt;li&gt;' . $category->name . '&lt;/li&gt;';

endforeach;
```

But I always get all created taxonomies, not only selected to post. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'city' ); ?>
```

You can learn more about this function [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tomas,

Here is solution for someone, who had same problem:

```
$citys = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'city' );                        
if ( $citys && ! is_wp_error( $citys ) ) :  $city_link = array();
    foreach ( $citys as $city ) {
        $city_link[] = '<a href="city/'.$city->slug.'">' . $city->name . '</a>';
    }                       
$cities = join( ", ", $city_link );
endif;
```